# Find the limit $\lim_{p\to\infty}(\int_0^1f ^p(x)dx)^\frac{1}{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

$$f \in C[0,1], f > 0$$
$$\lim_{p\to\infty}(\int_0^1f ^p(x)dx)^\frac{1}{p}$$
It is easy to see that the sequence is bounded above by the $\sup f$, but how can I bound it from below to prove that the limit is equal to $sup f$?

Comment: It is bounded below by $0$, since $f>0$.

Comment: So you only need a lower bound?

Comment: if you know limit exists, then it has a lower bound

Comment: I need bound it by the sequence converging to $sup f$ to prove that limit is $sup f$